# Jenkins remote ftp rsync

Tags: ftp, jenkins, maven-plugin, rsync, jenkins-plugins

I'm using jenkins on my project and I've set this into my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-upload-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
<configuration>
<serverId>ftpserver</serverId>
<resourceSrc>
${project.basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/*
</resourceSrc>
<resourceDest>/var/www/html</resourceDest>
<url>ftp://151.1.155.25/</url>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

now I want to copy only modified files on my remote host. Is it possible to use rsync option?
Or I have to use another kind of plug-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize a shell script to run the rsync for you, or the built in functionality to "transfer over ssh" I think it uses SCP or something similar. It will update/add but no deletes.